# Noncomformant argument in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Why am I getting this error? Where is problem?

```
>> x=1:1:10
x =
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

>> y=(2*pi)/(x)
error: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x10)
```

Comment: 2*pi is a scalar of length 1 and x is a vector of length 10. You are trying to divide 1 value with 10 values. Instead run y=(2*pi)./(x)

Comment: Thnx man.I got it.